# pyramid_beaker httponly and secure cookie

Tags: python, pyramid, beaker

After a security report, I've been asked to provide a secure session cookie.

I am using pyramid_beaker.session_factory_from_settings() and was lucky(?) to be able to set the httponly with `('session.httponly', True)`, but `('session.secure', True)` does not provide the second option.

Is it possible to do it?

Pointers to the different `session.*` settings much appreciated also.

*EDIT:* I found a list in `beaker.utils.coerce_session_params()`

Thanks.

*EDIT:* I think i got the problem. I am using in development:

```
        http_server = simple_server.make_server('0.0.0.0', no_port, app)
        http_server.serve_forever()
```

, so the cookie is not sent because I am not in HTTPS. I need to set up an HTTPs server for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, is there a question here? It sounds like you answered the original one and are now looking at making your development setup work under https? Personally I tend to worry about that only on my staging server (where nginx handles the certificates), but in my development.ini locally I do not make cookies secure.

Comment: Yes, I figured out why the "secure" cookie did not work. I was not using a deployment setup, but only a dev one, which is not HTTPS, but I did make the setup and it works. It was not easy to find what the `session.*` variables could be, that was my main problem. I ended up digging in the source code.